# R: Create count of observation + make occasion per observation group

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, count, sum

I have the following question, but I find difficulty in explaining it specifically and correctly in text. Thus, I would like to ask the question throughout the examples underneath:

**Original dataset**
(*in this dataset, the ID is the individual, the AMT is the amount administered and the DV is the measured biological value (dependent variable)*:

```
df_original=matrix(c(1,15,0,
                     1,0,20,
                     1,0,12,
                     1,0,4,
                     1,15,0,
                     1,0,8,
                     1,20,0,
                     1,20,0,
                     1,0,18,
                     2,60,0,
                     2,0,40,
                     2,0,6,
                     2,10,0,
                     2,10,0,
                     2,0,5), ncol=3, byrow=T)
colnames(df_original) = c('ID', 'AMT', 'DV')
rownames(df_original) = c(1:15)
df_original
```

**Wanted dataset** *(in this dataset, new column DVNR is the count of DV in total for the ID, the OCC is the occasion or measured concentration 'span' after each gift)*:

```
df_wanted=matrix(c(1,15,0,0,0,
                     1,0,20,1,1,
                     1,0,12,2,1,
                     1,0,4,3,1,
                     1,15,0,0,0,
                     1,0,8,4,2,
                     1,20,0,0,0,
                     1,20,0,0,0,
                     1,0,18,5,3,
                     2,60,0,0,0,
                     2,0,40,1,1,
                     2,0,6,2,1,
                     2,10,0,0,0,
                     2,10,0,0,0,
                     2,0,5,3,2), ncol=5, byrow=T)
colnames(df_wanted) = c('ID', 'AMT', 'DV', 'DVNR', 'OCC')
rownames(df_wanted) = c(1:15)
df_wanted
```

So far, the only code I know to achieve this is the first step

```
  df_Wanted <- df_Original %>%
  mutate(DVNR = ifelse(DV>0, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(DVNR2 = count(DVNR))
```

Code functions `count()` `tally()` `first()` so far have not led to success. Hunch feelings of `cumsum()` and `cummax()` are present, but not sure how to correctly implement them.

Possible a loop would work as well.

Is there something I am forgetting to try or can anyone help me with how to code for this in R?  I am quite new to R, my apologies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you reformat your wanted dataset so it's easier to understand? Is it supposed to be a table like your original dataset?

Comment: Hi! I edited the question. I am not sure yet how to make a tibble but this should work for any R console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can indeed use `cumsum()` for `DVNR`, but we have to wrap it in `ifelse`. The `OCC` is a little bit more trickier, we need `data.table::rleid()` (or from 'dplyr' v.1.1.0 we can use `consecutive_id()`) and take the integral division `%/%` by 2 wrapped in an `ifelse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_Original %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(DVNR = ifelse(DV !=0, cumsum(DV != 0), 0),
         OCC  = ifelse(DV == 0,
                       0,
                       data.table::rleid(DV == 0) %/% 2)
         )
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>       ID   AMT    DV  DVNR   OCC
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1    15     0     0     0
#>  2     1     0    20     1     1
#>  3     1     0    12     2     1
#>  4     1     0     4     3     1
#>  5     1    15     0     0     0
#>  6     1     0     8     4     2
#>  7     1    20     0     0     0
#>  8     1    20     0     0     0
#>  9     1     0    18     5     3
#> 10     2    60     0     0     0
#> 11     2     0    40     1     1
#> 12     2     0     6     2     1
#> 13     2    10     0     0     0
#> 14     2    10     0     0     0
#> 15     2     0     5     3     2
```

```r
df_Original  <- tribble(
  ~ ID, ~ AMT, ~  DV,
  1,  15  , 0 ,
  1,  0   , 20 ,
  1,  0   , 12 ,
  1,  0   , 4 ,
  1,  15  , 0 ,
  1,  0   , 8 ,
  1,  20  , 0 ,
  1,  20  , 0  ,
  1,  0   , 18 ,
  2,  60  , 0 ,
  2,  0   ,40 ,
  2,  0   , 6 ,
  2,  10  , 0 ,
  2,  10  , 0 ,
  2,  0   , 5 ,
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>